# Understanding hallo-image plugin

Tags: javascript, django, wagtail, hallo-js

I'm working to extend the `wagtailembedvideos` adding the properly `hallo.js` plugin: https://github.com/SalahAdDin/wagtail-embedvideos

I have this `embed-video-chooser.js`:

```
function createEmbedVideoChooser(id) {
    var chooserElement = $('#' + id + '-chooser');
    var previewEmbedVideo = chooserElement.find('.preview-image img');
    var input = $('#' + id);
    var editLink = chooserElement.find('.edit-link');

    $('.action-choose', chooserElement).click(function() {
        ModalWorkflow({
            'url': window.chooserUrls.embedVideoChooser,
            'responses': {
                'embedVideoChosen': function(embedVideoData) {
                    input.val(embedVideoData.id);
                    previewEmbedVideo.attr({
                        src: embedVideoData.preview.url,
                        width: embedVideoData.preview.width,
                        height: embedVideoData.preview.height,
                        alt: embedVideoData.title
                    });
                    chooserElement.removeClass('blank');
                    editLink.attr('href', embedVideoData.edit_link);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('.action-clear', chooserElement).on('click', function() {
        input.val('');
        chooserElement.addClass('blank');
    });
}
```

And this is the plugin:

```
(function() {
    (function($) {
        return $.widget('IKS.halloembedvideos', {
            options: {
                uuid: '',
                editable: null
            },
            populateToolbar: function(toolbar) {
                var button, widget;

                widget = this;
                button = $('<span class="' + this.widgetName + '"></span>');
                button.hallobutton({
                    uuid: this.options.uuid,
                    editable: this.options.editable,
                    label: 'Videos',
                    icon: 'icon-media',
                    command: null
                });
                toolbar.append(button);
                return button.on('click', function(event) {
                    var insertionPoint, lastSelection;

                    lastSelection = widget.options.editable.getSelection();
                    insertionPoint = $(lastSelection.endContainer).parentsUntil('.richtext').last();
                    return ModalWorkflow({
                        url: window.chooserUrls.embedVideoChooser + '?select_format=true',
                        responses: {
                            embedVideoChosen: function(embedVideoData) {
                                var elem;

                                elem = $(embedVideoData.html).get(0);
                                lastSelection.insertNode(elem);
                                if (elem.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'false') {
                                    insertRichTextDeleteControl(elem);
                                }

                                return widget.options.editable.element.trigger('change');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

The button [works](https://pasteboard.co/H5f0Gu4.png), the [chooser](https://pasteboard.co/H5f1b92.png) appears and i can upload or select the video, but i'm getting this error:

```
rangy-core.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
    at L (rangy-core.js:33)
    at I.insertNode (rangy-core.js:47)
    at Object.embedVideoChosen (hallo-embedvideos.js:33)
    at Object.ModalWorkflow.self.respond (modal-workflow.js:75)
    at Object.onload (eval at ModalWorkflow.self.loadResponseText (modal-workflow.js:54), <anonymous>:2:11)
    at Object.ModalWorkflow.self.loadBody (modal-workflow.js:68)
    at Object.ModalWorkflow.self.loadResponseText [as success] (modal-workflow.js:56)
    at i (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4)
```

I don't understand how `imageData.html` works, for this reason i don't know how can solve this problem.

Can anyone explain to me this?

Comment: Just an FYI: Wagtail 2.0 is right around the corner, and will be dropping the HalloJS editor in favor of the new Draftail editor. You may want to test with `pip install wagtail==2.0b1` to see if it works with the new editor instead. Good luck!

Comment: Actually i tested it, and i know you can still use `hallojs` editor in the new version.